# Request working correctly on Postman but gives a 404 error when I process it via React App

Tags: reactjs, rest, redux

I have been trying to working with [Github Gists API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/gists/gists?apiVersion=2022-11-28#star-a-gist), specifically the "Star a Gist"functionality but I am noticing a strange behavior when I send a request via my React app.

Here's the code for the request:

```
const starNote = async (noteId, token) => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      "Content-Length": "0",
    },
  }

  try {
    const response = await axios.put(`${API_URL}/${noteId}/star`, config, {
      noteId: noteId,
    })

    console.log("request sent")

    if (response.status === 204) {
      console.log("working", response)
      return true
    }
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response.status === 404) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
}
```

And here's the code for the slice function:

```
export const starNote = createAsyncThunk(
  "notes/starNote",
  async (noteId, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const token = thunkAPI.getState().auth.user.accessToken
      return await notesService.starNote(noteId, token)
    } catch (error) {
      const message =
        (error.response &&
          error.response.data &&
          error.response.data.message) ||
        error.message ||
        error.toString()
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message)
    }
  }
)
```

The action gets triggered correctly but the request doesn't go through the:

```
console.log("request sent")
```

part and goes straight to the error. If you send a GET request, it gives a 404 error if you haven't starred a gist. But for the PUT request, why does it go straight to the error and not send the request. If i try the same with Postman it works correctly and returns a

```
response.status: 204
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so what I did was insert this in the PUT request:

```
{ noteId: noteId }
```

And it worked.

Here's the complete code of the call:

```
const starNote = async (noteId, token) => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      "Content-Length": "0",
    },
  }

  try {
    const response = await axios.put(
      `${API_URL}/${noteId}/star`,
      { noteId: noteId },
      config
    )

    console.log("request sent")

    if (response.status === 204) {
      console.log("working", response)
      return true
    }
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response.status === 404) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
}
```

I am still not sure why it's necessary but this is what it needed.